# Good way to fit a .png file on Canvas?

Tags: image, canvas, tkinter

It seems to be a very common application, but I could not make it work:

def Img2Canvas(Img,Canv): # this function will put image on a canvas by stretching it

```
Canv.update()
H=Canv.winfo_height()
W=Canv.winfo_width()
print([W,H])

temp=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Img.resize((W,H)))
Canv.create_image(1,1,anchor=tk.NW,image=temp)
```

Then I called this function in main program:

```
cv1=tk.Canvas(root,width=200,height=200,bg='yellow')
Img2Canvas(p1.Img,cv1)
```

1) this does not work, The canvas is not updated, and I just got a Yellow background. It only works if I do not do `temp=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Img.resize((W,H)))` inside the function, but resize the image outside of function and input temp directly...

2) the `W` and `H` seems to be 204 instead of 200, so is `winfo_height()` always give you 4 more pixels?

3) is there a better way to display a figure file (jpg, png, etc.) in Tkinter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-edoes-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091)

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Thanks stovfl

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the image `temp` as it is a local variable which will be garbage collected after the function ends.  Suggest to return `temp` and assign it to a variable:

```
def Img2Canvas(Img, Canv):
    ...
    return temp

...
tkimg = Img2Canvas(p1.Img, cv1)
```

The extra pixels in the width and height is the size of `highlightthickness`, set it to 0 when creating the canvas:

```
cv1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, highlightthickness=0, bg='yellow')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, acw1668.  But if I just want the Img2Canvas function to update Canvas, once it does that, I dont really care to keep a copy of temp.... Whether I keep temp in memory or not, cv1 should be updated already, right? or it will be flushed blank if temp is gone?

Comment: The image will be lost if `temp` is garbage collected.

Comment: Or you can replace the line `return temp` to `Img.tkimg = temp` to keep the reference.

Comment: I see. I used to use temp to update Widgets like button's text or color of something, then garbage the temp when exiting function. It looks like Canvas does not store the displaced Image within itself, it is just a reference. so when temp is out, Canvas has nothing to show... Great! I got it to work and thanks a lot for the help!!!